# Why can't you convert containers using .into() if the elements can be converted?

Tags: rust, vector, collections, hashmap

If I have a `Vec<T>` I can't convert it into `Vec<U>` directly using `.into()` even if I can convert `T` into `U` using `.into()`. For example this code does not compile:

```
use std::convert::From;

struct A {
    x: i32,
}

struct B {
    y: u64,
}

impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(a: A) -> Self {
        Self {
            y: a.x as u64,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let avec: Vec<A> = vec![A{x: 1}, A{x: 2}];
    let bvec: Vec<B> = avec.into(); // Error!
}
```

I feel like it should be possible to have a blanket impl something like this:

```
impl<T, U> From<Vec<T>> for Vec<U> where T: From<U> {
    fn from(t: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        t.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect()
    }
}
```

And similarly for the other collections. Is there a reason this was not done? It would save a lot of tedious code when you want to convert, say a `HashMap<String, Vec<Vec<u32>>>` to a `HashMap<String, Vec<Vec<u64>>>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue (currently) with having a blanket implementation for converting containers, is that it conflicts with the existing blanket implementation [`impl From<T> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#generic-implementations).

To be able to get around that, it would in short require [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) ([Issue #31844](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844)).

```rust
// This:
impl<T, U> From<Vec<T>> for Vec<U> where T: From<U>

// Would conflicts with this:
impl<T> From<T> for T
```

The same question was discussed on the Rust forum not long ago:

- [Converting iterators as a blanket implementation](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/converting-iterators-as-a-blanket-implementation/50111)